# What is an example of "this" assignment in C#?

Tags: c#, language-features

Does anybody have useful example of `this` assignment inside a C# method? I have been asked for it once during job interview, and I am still interested in answer myself.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The other answers are incorrect when they say you cannot assign to 'this'.  True, you can't for a class type, but you *can* for a struct type:

```
public struct MyValueType
{
    public int Id;
    public void Swap(ref MyValueType other)
    {
        MyValueType temp = this;
        this = other;
        other = temp;
    }
}
```

At any point a struct can alter itself by assigning to 'this' like so.

Comment: Ohhh it's because as a struct it is a value type and the assignment operator = with value types copies values.

Comment: Enlightening! Subjective Comment: however apart from the Swap(ref struct) scenario, I can't think of anything else that can benefit from this. this cannot be used before assigning all members of that struct. I'd rather use the s2 = s1 instead of having a method with this used as above.

Comment: Also have not seen this before  :)

Comment: With C#, you never have to wonder why you love it - it's always reminding you.

Answer (score 0):

using the **this** keyword ensures that only variables and methods scoped in the current type are accessed. This can be used when you have a naming conflict between a field/property and a local variable or method parameter.

Typically used in constructors:

```
private readonly IProvider provider;
public MyClass(IProvider provider)
{
  this.provider = provider;
}
```

In this example we assign the parameter provider to the private field provider.

Comment: Is not an example of assigning to `this`.

Answer (score -1):

only correct place for this from syntax point of view, is Extension methods in C# 3.0 when you specify first parameter of method as foo(ftype this, ...). and then can use this extension for any instance of ftype. But is's just syntax and not real this ovveride operation.

Comment: Not true. Values types can assign to `this` and there is no other syntax for it.

Answer (score -1):

if you're asked to assign something to *this*, there's quite a few examples. One that comes to mind is telling a control who his daddy is:

```
class frmMain
{
    void InitializeComponents()
    {
        btnOK = new Button();
        btnOK.Parent = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is not an example of assigning to `this`.

Answer (score -1):

I know this question has long been answered and discussion has stopped, but here's a case I didn't see mentioned anywhere on the interwebs and thought it may be useful to share here.

I've used this to maintain immutability of members while still supporting serialization. Consider a `struct` defined like this:

```
public struct SampleStruct : IXmlSerializable
{
    private readonly int _data;

    public int Data { get { return _data; } }

    public SampleStruct(int data)
    {
         _data = data;
    }

    #region IXmlSerializableMembers

    public XmlSchema GetSchema() { return null; }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        this = new SampleStruct(int.Parse(reader.ReadString()));
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer
    {
        writer.WriteString(data.ToString());
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Since we're allowed to overwrite `this`, we can maintain the immutability of `_data` held within a single instance.  This has the added benefit of when deserializing new values you're guaranteed a fresh instance, which is sometimes a nice guarantee!
    }

Comment: You've just created a mutable value type.  And worse still, you create a mutable value type that *appears* as if it's immutable at first glance.  This is all kinds of evil.

Comment: I would recommend explicitly implementing the IXmlSerializable interface for a little more safety, but then the question becomes, is it ever OK to have a serializable struct, since in order to be serializable you need to be mutable in some sense.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot overwrite "this". It points to the current object instance.

Comment: Not true for value types.